# Ubuntu 15.04 Sticky Edges

Tags: unity, 15.04

It's possible to enable the sticky edges in the corners? Not only in both sides of the screen, but in the 4 corners like in Ubuntu 14.04 or Windows 10.

Comment: Please install a supported Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Yes you can do this using the unity tweak tool, which can be found in the default software sources. once in unity tweak tool go to the windows snapping section and configure it as you like.

2 Please update to 15.10, as 15.04 is no longer supported and you will most likely have your questions taken down unless you update.